# RubyMineでファイルツリーをフィルタリングしたい

Tags: rubymine

## フォルダもサーチ対象にしつつツリー状でフィルタリングを行いたい

`HogeController`について編集したいなと思うと、それに紐付いて
`views/hoge/index.html.erb`, `models/hoge.rb`,
`config/locales/配下/hoges/ja.yml`, `その他hogeが付く関連ファイル`
というように`hoge`という命名規則で紐付いたファイルとフォルダ配下も編集したくなります。
そこで、フォルダ、ファイルともにフィルタリングできる方法を探しています。

### Xcodeのフィルター機能が理想です

Xcodeにはファイルツリーのフィルター機能があります。

#### フィルター前（絞込前）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### フィルター後（絞込後）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### RubyMineで似たような機能

RubyMineでは下記のような似たような機能がありますが、
欲しい機能と完全にマッチしませんでした。

ファイルツリー内の検索モード

ファイルツリーでアルファベットをタイプすると検索モードとなって
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
ファイルを検索してくれますが、対象がフォルダーを開いた状態のものに限られ、さらに該当したファイルをハイライトで見せてくれるだけです。
ファイル数が多いので、全フォルダーを開いた状態でハイライトされてもそもそもツリーが画面に収まりきっていないので、可読性が悪いです。

Cmd + Shift + oした後pinのマークを押すのが一番近い？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
Cmd + Shift + oした後pinのマークを押すのが一番近いように思います。
pinを押した後は、[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]Findペインに絞りこまれたファイルツリーが現れます。ただ、絞りこみ対象がファイル名のみで、フォルダ名は対象に入れてもらえないので、フォルダを見落としてしまいます。（フォルダーが検索対象になっていないので、i18n用のyamlなどが漏れる）

Comment: 「で、結局知りたいことはなんですか？」となってしまったので、質問内容をもっと明確にされた方が良いと思います。

Comment: @Junichi Ito 追記いたしました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Cmd + Shift + oした後pinのマークを押すのが一番近いように思います

確かにこれが一番近そうです。

> フォルダ名は対象に入れてもらえない

"hoge/"のようにスラッシュを入れるとフォルダ（ディレクトリ）も検索対象になります。

参考： [Navigating to Class, File Or Symbol by Name](https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/help/navigating-to-class-file-or-symbol-by-name.html)